# Can't paste files or create folders in a file browser on my root or /opt

Tags: permissions, root

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 in VirtualBox.

I would like to unpack a tar.gz in my root (`/`) folder but I can't paste any file in it or even create a new folder in the file browser.

I can do that with command line when I use `sudo` but when I use right click I don't have access to **create new folder** or **paste**... I have `sudo` privilege so I don't really understand.

I think it can by done with terminal because with `mkdir` I've been able to create a folder, but I can't write in this folder.

Does anybody have any clue about it?

Comment: What I mean by I am root user is that I have admin rights. I can do any sudo command line. This file contain a package that is suppossed to go in the opt folder. (When I open my tar.gz with archive manager I can see there is the opt/ folder then in it the soft I need) and I'm also following a tutorial that telling me to unpack it in my root folder in order to install it in the opt folder.

Comment: My point here is that I'm not using any command line I'm trying to do it with the manager. With command line I believe everything works fine but I don't understand why I can't access directly to my opt folder. When I open /opt then right click I can't add new folder, paste file.... (not sure to be clear)

Comment: Thanks, I understand better now. I tried this command line : `sudo tar -xvfz tc_arm_gcc-4.4.4-glibc-2.11.1-multilib-1.0.i386.tar.gz` and got this error : 
`"tar: z : open impossible: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now` the french part says that there is no file or folder of this type. But the spelling is good and my file is in my "/" folder

Comment: Also why do you don't recommend to run file browser with root privilege ?

Comment: Maybe the z option is not required... does it work without it?

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't recommend running the file browser as root because in the command line you usually run one command with `sudo` and that's it. It's easy to do a lot of operations in a file browser without thinking about the fact that you are doing all of them as root. If you are careful and close the program as soon as you've done what you need, it's fine, but you should be aware that you can easily cause damage to the system when running things as root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do the following from your terminal:

```
sudo -H nautilus
```

that way you will get *all* the privileges like as root to make folders and paste stuffs everywhere you want.

Comment: Thank you it works, I saw it thanks to Zanna's example !

Comment: And what happens when it goes wrong with an edit of a config file in user home dir? Don't do this, it should have been `sudo -H nautilus` see `man sudo`

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I've edited my answer.